# Iframe google plus on a right to left website

Tags: iframe, google-plus, right-to-left

I have a problem using the googlePlus button to sign in. 
When I call https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js two iframes are created in my websites.

I have two websites, one in english and another in arabian for which I use the right to left direction.

the iframes have this style :
position : absolute 
left : -100px

For the english siteweb everything is ok but for the arabian one, I have to put :
right : -100px

If I don't do that I have a marge on my left side.

I search in the configuration to specify A right to Left but I don't find.  And if I don't say bullsheets it's not possible to change the style of an ouside Iframe.

So If anyone has already faces this problem or have an idea ....

Thank you a lot and I hope to have a response soon :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the Google+ button renders in an HTML element, it will override all of the styles associated with it. To work around this, create an outer element around the button and apply your style to that button.  For example:

```
<div id="outerdiv" style="position: absolute; left: -100px">
  <div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium" data-annotation="inline" data-width="300"></div>
</div>
```